# Can't use other languages(except English) on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to make an alert message in another language in my android app. But those texts do not appear in Android studio. They appear as some unknown character types as shown [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHqMJ.jpg)

How can I solve this?

Comment: try restarting AS.

Comment: I tried restarting. But it didn't help@UmangBurman

Answer (score 2):

While this doesn't really answer your question,

I suggest that instead of using hardcoded strings, use the Android resources system to support multiple languages,

For example:

**English** strings (default locale), `/values/strings.xml`:

```
<resources>
  <string name="hello_world">Hello World!</string>
</resources>
```

**Spanish** strings (es locale), `/values-es/strings.xml`:

```
<resources>
  <string name="hello_world">¡Hola Mundo!</string>
</resources>
```

Then use the language resource like this:

```
showMessage(getString(R.string.error_title), getString(R.string.hello_world));
```

Comment: This method was not supporting me to solve the issue. Anyway thanks dude@HedeH